# Compilation error on variable declaration in QTP

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, vbscript

I just started to learn QTP 11.00 In one program I am getting one compilation error on this line on QTP tool

```
Dim plus = 10
```

Here I am unable to understand this what is wrong with this line please help here.

Answer (score 3):

This was surprisingly difficult to track down.

VBScript does not allow a variable to be declared and assigned in the same statement.

You need to change your code to

```
Dim plus
plus = 10
```